# How do I make my logo link back to home page in wordpress twenty twelve child theme?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am currently developing a website with the WordPress Twenty Twelve theme and I have made a few changes of my own.

One of these changes is to the header and I have replaced the site title with an image, but now I want to make this image link back to the home page.

Below is the line of code of which makes the image appear on the site, I am hoping there is someway of adding a link in there to get the image to link to the homepage.

> ```
>   <img class="sitelogo" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/logo.png" alt="site logo"/>
> ```

I have looked into different ways of doing this however the way I have done this, the image looks fine where it is.

Comment: Wrap the image tag in a link tag

Comment: You should copy the twenty-twelve theme into a new theme folder and work on that, as any changes you make to twenty-twelve theme itself could be overridden with updates to the theme. See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: I have done that James, got it all fixed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Errm, how about a link?

```
<a href="<?php echo get_option("siteurl"); ?>"><img class="sitelogo" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/logo.png" alt="site logo"/></a>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! I was overthinking where it would go, I thought I would have had to have dropped it in the middle of that line of code somewhere. Thank you very much.

Comment: Got to wait a couple of minutes :-(

Comment: The homepage of the wordpress instance does not necessarily have to be `/`. If you want a general solution you should use `<a href="<?php echo get_option("siteurl"); ?>"></a>` instead.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider you're right.. I'll update my answer!